# tenho esse código que verifica se o numero inserido é par ou Impar, mas quero adicionar uma condição caso o usuário não insira nenhum Valor

Tags: javascript

```
var valor = 0;
var tipo = "";
var semValor = false;



function impar_par(num){
   
     if( num % 2 == 0){
        document.write("Valor inserido: ");
        tipo = "Par";

    }else{
        document.write("Valor Inserido: ");
        tipo = "Impar";
    }
        
    
    return tipo; // retorna o valor do numero inseriro sendo impar ou 

}


document.write(impar_par(prompt("Digite um numero: ")));
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Não complique: https://jsfiddle.net/wqkbpjfL/ - Repare que vc mostra a mensagem "valor inserido" tanto no `if` quanto no `else`, ou seja, ela sempre será mostrada. Sendo assim, achei melhor chamá-la sempre apenas uma vez antes da função (poderia ser dentro também, mas enfim). E incluí uma validação para ver se foi digitado um número mesmo (e faço a conversão explícita para número - apesar de muitas vezes "não precisar", eu prefiro fazer pra evitar conversões implícitas que [nem sempre fazem o que vc espera](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat))

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso, é só adicionar adicionar um if para ver se a variável num é uma string vazia (""), que é o valor dela caso o usuário só dê ok sem digitar nada. O código ficaria assim:

```
var tipo = "";

    function impar_par(num) {
        if (num === ""){
            alert("Digite um número!");
            window.location.reload();
        }
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
        document.write("Valor inserido: ");
        tipo = "Par";

        } else {
            document.write("Valor Inserido: ");
            tipo = "Ímpar";
        }


            return tipo; // retorna o valor do numero inseriro sendo impar ou 

    }


    document.write(impar_par(prompt("Digite um numero: ")));
```

As variáveis valor e semValor são desnecessárias. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: muito obrigado por me esclarecer Davi, sucesso

Answer (score -1):

```
var tipo = "";

    function impar_par(num) {
        if (num === isNaN()){
            alert("Insira um número");
        }

        if (num % 2 == 0) {
        document.write("Valor inserido: ");
        tipo = "Par";

        } else {
            document.write("Valor Inserido: ");
            tipo = "Ímpar";
        }


            return tipo; // retorna o valor do numero inseriro sendo impar ou 

    }


    document.write(impar_par(prompt("Digite um numero: ")));
```

Pode usar o Null visto ser um valor primitivo

Comment: obrigado Filipe vou refatora o código para verificar a implementação

Comment: mudei para isNaN() para englobar um maior numero de erros

Comment: O certo seria `isNaN(num)` e não `num === isNaN()`. Além disso, se entrar nesse primeiro `if` já deveria retornar, mas no seu código ele continua testando se é par mesmo assim... E a mensagem de "valor inserido" está tanto no `if` quanto no `else`, então ela poderia estar fora deles...